# How to copy a track from Bing Maps to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I have a track in Bing Maps, but I'd like to get it somehow to Google Maps. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the route in Bing Maps as a KML file & import that KML file into Google Maps.

In Bing Maps, add the selected location to a Collection. The "Add to collection" link appears below any location you choose.

From the Collection menu on the right, click on "Open your collections" to view the Collections Editor which has an Actions dropdown. This has the Export option under it which further shows the KML & GeoRSS option under it. (there may be alternative ways of reaching this Export to KML option). This will allow you to download the selected route as a KML or GeoRSS file.

In Google Maps, click on the My Places button & then click on the Create Map button.  Select the Import link & upload the KML or GeoRSS file that you've copied from Bing.